# Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding. The old Tor Browser process must be closed to open a new window

Tags: windows

why do i keep getting'Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding. The old Tor Browser process must be closed to open a new window.' even when i turn off my computer and turn it back on or reset?
also I cant seem to close it in my task manager

Comment: please post your hardware specs

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to reinstall the latest version of Tor Browser.